# What's the favoured way of allowing anonymous users access to a private Plone folder?

Tags: authorization, plone, plone-4.x

I want to allow anonymous users view access to a private folder & it's contents, only after they have submitted a valid email address through a form.  I thought of emailing them a link to the folder, perhaps with a token that gives them access or logs them in, but I'm not quite sure how to do that.

I'm currently looking at [collective.powertoken.core](https://github.com/RedTurtle/collective.powertoken.core) & [collective.powertoken.view](https://github.com/RedTurtle/collective.powertoken.view), but it seems that these products cover access to a single content item, rather than a whole folder.

I'm wondering if it's better just to add low priviledged users to the system & log them in without passwords.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as suggested by @keul, you can use `redomino.tokenrole`.

If you want to integrate the `tokenrole` feature with a `PloneFormGen` you might consider to have a look at `redomino.tokenroleform` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redomino.tokenroleform): 
It is a custom plone form gen adapter that let you share a private object via token.

I don't know if `redomino.tokenroleform` fits your use case.

But you can browse the code in order to understand how to add a tokenrole programmatically.

Comment: Yes! That's a very good fit for my use case. I'm only wondering whether it allows access only to a single document - or a whole folder of content, which is what I need.

Comment: tokenrole is not suitable for sharing a whole folder, just single items. For example tokenrole+tokenrole form is a perfect solution for sharing a private file (pdf?) with anonymous users thanks to a timed token, different for each submission. It's something like a "pay with a form submission" solution.

Answer (score 1):

Both products are for very low level usage.

Try redomino.tokenrole: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redomino.tokenrole

Comment: Thansk. I saw this - but how can I add the token from a script (eg a PFG Custom Script adaptor)?

Comment: @Danimal: probably not out of the box (I don't remember the source), but I think is your best choice.